# Is there a VS code extension to show a list of options for css?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a VS code extension that lets users view options for CSS?

For example:

```
body {
 cursor: (at this point I want to see the extension telling me what my options are. Such as 'pointer', 'default', 'move', 'wait' and etc) 
}
```

Just thought it would save my time to go on w3school to see what my options are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out IntelliSense for CSS: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion

Not sure if it does it automatically, but with `Ctrl` + `Space` it shows a list of suggestions:

[image]

Also, if you press the same combination while having the list, you'll get a description:

[image]